# Pure HTML/CSS table with sticky header, horizontal scroll and dynamic cell width?

Tags: html, css, html-table, sticky

I need pure HTML/CSS table with features:

- sticky header when scrolling page vertically
- content based cell widths (header cell is as wide as widest cell in column)
- horizontal scrolling, which does not break one of the above

I can easily prepare snippet with two out of three bullets from above, but tagging all is bending my mind.

Does anyone has ready to work snippet or an idea how to achieve this? Appreciate any word of advice.

@edit Work in progress in here: https://codepen.io/mslawins/pen/PEQRyJ
Also CSS part below:

```
table {
  margin: auto;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;

  display: block;
  border-collapse: collapse;

  //overflow-x: scroll; // adding this breaks sticky
}

th {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px; // without this "header collapses", when using sticky/block trick
  padditable {
  margin: auto;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;

  display: block;
  border-collapse: collapse;

  //overflow-x: scroll; // adding this breaks sticky
}

th {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px; // without this "header collapses", when using sticky/block trick
  padding: 3px;
}

td {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100px; // without this, width is content based, but this does not propagate to th,
  //  because of sticky/block trick
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

thead {
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

thead tr {
  display: table;
}
```

Comment: Try including the code you've tried so far - it makes it much easier for everyone to help and advice (ps. I didnt downvote). It's expected that one at least tries before asking on stackoverflow and present the things which one have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sticky header (using `position: sticky`) is not possible inside a container with scrolling [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). So, no way to achieve that without JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using div tables and position:sticky

```
.td.header {
  position: sticky;
  top:0px;
}
```

Check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0xkaufs/) for simple example.